# Use external audio stream as microphone input for Twilio Voice call

Tags: twilio, gstreamer, audio-streaming, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I want to use an incoming audio stream (microphone from an *external* device) as the microphone input for an outbound Twilio Voice call.

The external device serves as a softphone, and does not currently support WebRTC. Instead it currently sets up 2 separate connections to a server: 1 for outgoing audio (microphone), and 1 for incoming audio. Bots connections (streams) are set up using gstreamer (`gst-launch`).

The server sets up a voice call and should somehow use the incoming audio stream as the microphone input for this call. I have already found the [Stream](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) instruction able to send the calls' audio back to the external device.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, maybe suggest some SDK functionality?

Comment: What is the external device?

Comment: @Brad The external device is an embedded system, comparable to Appe HomePod or Google Home

Comment: Does the device support SIP? It might be easier to set it up that way.

Comment: @philnash Not at the moment, but if you think it is a viable option, we can look into implementing it. Can you provide us with eg a link to Twilio's documentation which we can use as a starting point? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound) and the [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-registration).